# size of struct field from ncinfo

Tags: matlab, struct, netcdf

I want to get the size of a certain field inside a structure.

For example the size of the field `Name` inside the field `Dimensions` of the struct obtained from `ncinfo`:

```
finfo = ncinfo('example.nc');
finfo.Dimensions.Name

>>ans =

x


ans =

y


ans =

z
```

Just using `size` causes an obvious error:

`size(finfo.Dimensions.Name)`

> Error using size 
>   Too many input arguments.

How can I do it in an alternative way?

Also, I would like to save the content of `finfo.Dimensions.Name` in a separate array or struct. But I get a similar error. For example:

```
a.b=finfo.Dimensions.Name
```

returns the error:

> Illegal right hand side in assignment. Too many elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `Dimensions` field in the structure returned by [`ncinfo`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ncinfo.html) is itself an [array of structures](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-structure-array.html), and when you access a field of a structure array it returns a [comma-separated list of values](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html#br2js35-6), one for each array element. You need to collect these values, for example in a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html):

```
nameCell = {finfo.Dimensions.Name};  % Now a 1-by-3 cell array of names
```

If you just want to know the number of dimensions, you can check the size of the `Dimensions` field like so:

```
N = size(finfo.Dimensions);
```

Answer (score 2):

Per the [documentation for `ncinfo`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ncinfo.html), `Dimensions` is an *array* of structures, so you need to be more explicit with what you want to do.

If you want the [`size`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) of the `'Dimensions'` field then that is your query:

```
S.Dimensions(1).Name = 'x';
S.Dimensions(2).Name = 'y';
S.Dimensions(3).Name = 'z';

size(S.Dimensions)
```

Which returns:

```
ans =

     1     3
```